# Replace all occurences in string except the ones starting with "http" or "https" with php

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a function in php where I want to replace all occurences of "www." with "http://www.".

```
$text = preg_replace("www\.", "http://www.", $data);
```

I've tried using this code but I do not want the string "http://www." to be turned into "http://http://www.".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `^` anchor to you regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^www\./", "http://www.", $data);
                       ^ -- this one
```

*NB: mind the regex delimiters (`/.../`) in the pattern parameter.*

This start of line anchorhelps to ensure the `www.` string to be replaced is at the beginning of the `$data` string. It will prevent any undesired substitutions in the middle of a string like this: `redirector.com/?www.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a negative lookbehind:

```
'~(?<!://)www\.~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT5eC7/1)

The `(?<!://)` lookbehind will fail a match if `www.` is preceded with `://` thus avoiding the match in `http://www.` and `https://www.`.

If you really want to avoid matching strings that have `http://` only, add `http` or `\bhttp` before the `:` and use `'~(?<!http://)www\.~'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will check for not only HTTP, but also other protocols like HTTPS, FTP etc.

```
function addPrefix($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}

echo addPrefix("http://ww.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a negative lookbehind:

```
(?!http://)www\.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified code

```
 i.e  $url='www.xyz.com';
            function urlModified($patterns, $replace, $url)
            {
              $patterns = array ('http://www.');
              $replace = array ('/^www\./');
              preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $url);
              return $url;
            }
```